# unslick() without destroying the entire carousel

Tags: javascript, carousel, slick.js

I have a SlickJS carousel that I want to work as normal on Desktop but on Mobile I want it to just have the slides stacked on top of one another. I am trying to reproduce the behaviour on this website which does this and uses SlickJS too ->

https://www.liquid.com.au/about

It's the 'What we’re good at.' section.

I tried `responsive: "unslick"` for anything below 968px but that removes the slides, which I need so I can style them differently.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out you can achieve this by activating grid mode by using the `rows` property:

```
      responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 968,
      settings: {
        rows: 6
      }
    }
  ]
```